# Evaluating $\iint_R x^2\,\mathrm dA$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am learning multivariable calculus myself and came across the double integral $\iint_R x^2\, \mathrm dA$ where $R$ is the region bounded by $y=x,y=\frac{16}x,x=8,y=0 $.

I was able to evaluate the integral by treating the region as a type I region.

I got
$$ \iint_R x^2\,\mathrm dA = \int_0^4\int_0^x x^2\,dydx +\int_4^8 \int\limits_0^{16/x}x^2\, dydx = 448$$

But I wasn't able to evaluate it by treating the region as a type II region, as I can't set the limits.

1. Is my result correct?
2. How can I set the limits for the type II region?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the highly author-specific terms "type I region", "type II region" and whatever type III, type IV, type MMMDCLXVII regions, but the region $R$ does not contain any point $(x,y)$ from $0<x<4$..

Comment: @user1035 By type I region, I mean keeping $x$ fixed. Type II region means to keep $y$ fixed. A bit of graphing using Wolfram|Alpha assures me that you are incorrect in your second point.

Comment: @user1035, here is a plot of the region
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dx%2C+y%3D16%2Fx%2C+x%3D8%2C+y%3D0+from+x%3D0+to+9

Comment: Where does the $y=0$ come from?

Comment: @user1035, oops. I forgot to mention that in my post. Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps a clearer plot of the integration region: https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: Adding that $\;y=0\;$ makes it completely changed the integration domain....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the order of integral from $dy \ dx$ to $dx \ dy$.

[image]

At intersection of $xy = 16$ and $y = x$, $x = y = 4$

At intersection of $x = 8, xy = 16$, $y = 2$.

For $0 \leq y \leq 2$, region is bound between lines $y = x$ and $x = 8$.

For $2 \leq y \leq 4$, region is bound between line $y = x$ and curve $xy = 16$.

Please see the shaded area in the diagram. That is the region you need to integrate over.

The integral will be,

$\displaystyle \int_0^2 \int_y^8 x^2 \ dx \ dy + \int_2^4 \int_y^{16/y} x^2 \ dx \ dy$

Comment: Thanks a lot. (+1)

Comment: I lose my control when someone embellishes the answer with an illustration.

Comment: @Mikasa sorry I made you lose control :)

Comment: @Mikasa :) yes thank GOD, I would have a lot of explaining to do and that it was never on purpose.... ok before someone reminds me of not using comments for entertainment purpose, let me stop :)